# [undefined local variable or method `current_user' in controller]

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, controller, helper

I've been around for this problem for 1 hour and not figuring out why it doesn't work.

I don't use gem devise.
I have user model, post model, UsersController.rb, PostsController.rb and 1 helper like below

1. PostsController.rb :

```
class PostsController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_post, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]

  # GET /posts
  # GET /posts.json
  def index
    @posts = Post.all
  end

  # GET /posts/1
  # GET /posts/1.json
  def show
  end

  # GET /posts/new
  def new
    @post = Post.new
  end

  # GET /posts/1/edit
  def edit
  end

  # POST /posts
  # POST /posts.json
  def create
    @post = current_user.posts.build(post_params)

    respond_to do |format|
      if @post.save
        format.html { redirect_to @post, notice: 'Post was successfully created.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @post }
      else
        format.html { render :new }
        format.json { render json: @post.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  # PATCH/PUT /posts/1
  # PATCH/PUT /posts/1.json
  def update
    respond_to do |format|
      if @post.update(post_params)
        format.html { redirect_to @post, notice: 'Post was successfully updated.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :ok, location: @post }
      else
        format.html { render :edit }
        format.json { render json: @post.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  # DELETE /posts/1
  # DELETE /posts/1.json
  def destroy
    @post.destroy
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { redirect_to posts_url, notice: 'Post was successfully destroyed.' }
      format.json { head :no_content }
    end
  end

  private
    # Use callbacks to share common setup or constraints between actions.
    def set_post
      @post = Post.find(params[:id])
    end

    # Never trust parameters from the scary internet, only allow the white list through.
    def post_params
      params.require(:post).permit(:caption, :user_id)
    end
end
```

2. ApplicationHelper.rb

```
module ApplicationHelper
    def current_user
        session[:user_id] && User.find(session[:user_id])
    end
end
```

The current_user helper method works fine for all the views.

As I understand, PostsController inherits from ApplicationController, so it takes all the helpers from ApplicationHelper. I still dont figure out why this doesn't work.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: I think `ApplicationHelper` is deprecated - see https://apidock.com/rails/ApplicationHelper. I have not personally used controller helpers before but I found this link which has docs https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionController/Helpers.html and the method you have to call https://apidock.com/rails/AbstractController/Helpers/ClassMethods/helper

Comment: Probably this will work. I will try it

Answer (score 1):

Try with adding this into `ApplicationController.rb`

```
helper_method :current_user
```

Comment: You should also move your current user method directly into the controller, a concern, or the application controller.

Answer (score -1):

call helper methods in Rails 5 :

```
# sample : 

module UsersHelper
  def full_name(user)
    user.first_name + user.last_name
  end
end

class UsersController < ApplicationController

  def update
    @user = User.find params[:id]
    if @user.update_attributes(user_params)
      notice = "#{helpers.full_name(@user) is successfully updated}"
      redirect_to user_path(@user), notice: notice
    else
      render :edit
    end
  end
end
```

Before Rails 5 :

```
# sample :

module UsersHelper
  def full_name(user)
    user.first_name + user.last_name
  end
end

class UsersController < ApplicationController
  include UsersHelper

  def update
    @user = User.find params[:id]
    if @user.update_attributes(user_params)
      redirect_to user_path(@user), notice: "#{full_name(@user) is successfully updated}"
    else
      render :edit
    end
  end
end
```